# Amazon Lex Facebook Messenger Webhook and getting Page Scoped ID

Tags: aws-lambda, facebook-messenger, amazon-lex

I'm currently doing some proof of concept stuff with Amazon Lex, Lambda, and the Facebook Messenger Webhook integration for chatbots.

I see through Facebook's Webhook that when messages are sent to Lex, they include a user ID (which I believe is the Page Scoped ID).

Through Lambda initialization and validation with Amazon Lex, I don't see this page scoped ID passed anywhere in the *event* object inside of Lambda, which leads me to believe Lex if formatting the event and stripping out any body content that is passed from Facebook.

Is there a way to read the body content of the incoming request?

Answer (score 1):

When accessing Lex through Facebook, Lex will pass Facebook data to your Lambda Function inside of `event.requestAttributes`. This is the structure:

```
"requestAttributes": {
    "x-amz-lex:facebook-page-id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",  
    "x-amz-lex:channel-id": "XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",  
    "x-amz-lex:webhook-endpoint-url": "https://channels.lex.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/facebook/webhook/XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX",  
    "x-amz-lex:accept-content-types": "PlainText",  
    "x-amz-lex:user-id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",  
    "x-amz-lex:channel-name": "FacebookLexBotAppName",  
    "x-amz-lex:channel-type": "Facebook"  
},
```

To get the **Page Access Token** = `event.requestAttributes['x-amz-lex:facebook-page-id']`
To get the **PSID (Page Scoped ID)** = `event.requestAttributes['x-amz-lex:user-id']`